# Bootstrap accordion ajax load only on click

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Im wondering if its possible to load an ajax to a accordion only if the content is active. This would avoid unnecessary data loading. There could be somekind of spinner added meanwhile loading. Have been looking through the internet and haven't found any solution. Thanks.

Here is the raw accordion example

http://www.bootply.com/117967

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#myCollapsiblePanel').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
   var itemId  = $(e.target).attr('id').replace('prefix_for_the_ID_of_panel-collapse-div','');
   //$(e.target) refers to the panel-collapse div. 
   //use the itemId to get the relevant data from server via ajax
   //then you can populate the panel-collapse div. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a panel shown event that you can use.

```
$('#myCollapsiblePanel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do ajaxy stuff…
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage

Comment: Maybe, but how to get the id and append the output result of ajax to the body?

Comment: Are you asking how to write ajax? That seems beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I know how to (the php part - and just how to call if from jq ) but how to get the id and set the value to field. I think its still the same question.